# Make Antd React's Select component Accessible

Tags: reactjs, accessibility

I am using [React Antd 3.x Select Component](https://3x.ant.design/components/select/) and when I run [Axe Web Accessibility Test](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/axe-web-accessibility-tes/lhdoppojpmngadmnindnejefpokejbdd) using the chrome plugin, I get the violation "Certain ARIA roles must contain particular children". Please suggest.

I have added "role=option" for the options in Select, but still a violation

[Codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-herschel-wkv3j?file=/index.js)

Answer (score 0):

Added the Options Display String in a span as give it some required fields. May be workaround. Edited the same codesandbox link